# How do I disable jshint for entire folder in a project using .jshintrc

Tags: javascript, jshint

How do I disable jshint for entire folder in a project using .jshintrc

I am getting jshint error in every file in a project. I don't need jshint for that particular project.

How can I disable jshint using .jshintrc

I found that you can exclude jshint by using following code in vscode `settings.json`

```
"jslint.exclude": {
     "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\tmp": true,
     "**\\*.es6": true
}
```

but the problem is if I change the location I am getting errors again.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can accomplish this with the `.jshintrc` file. However, if you need to disable jshint for the entire project, you can disable it in the workspace settings.

Within a folder at the root of your project called `.vscode`, create a file called `settings.json`. Within this file, set this property:

```
{
    "jshint.enable": false
}
```